# При подключении browserSync и последующих изменениях страница не обновляется

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, less

Хочу подключить `browserSync` для автоперезагрузки страницы при изменениях `less`.
`less` компилируется в css, но при следующих изменениях страница не обновляется.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('less', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/less/**/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))    
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true })) 
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() { 
    browserSync({ 
        server: { 
            baseDir: 'app' 
        },
        notify: false 
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel('browser-sync', 'less'), function () {
  gulp.watch('app/less/**/*.less', gulp.series['less']);
});
```

Comment: Ошибку пишет какую то? логи есть? сайт на локальном сервере открываете?

Comment: Открываю на локальном сервере. Ошибку не пишет. При команде watch открывает сайт заново,но не следит за изменениями. Надеюсь дала всю информацию)Я новичок в этомю

Answer (score 1):

Проверил поправил, вот так будет работать.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('less', function(){ // Создаем таск Less
    return gulp.src('app/less/**/*.less') // Берем источник
        .pipe(less()) // Преобразуем Less в CSS посредством gulp-Less
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) // Выгружаем результата в папку app/css
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})) // Обновляем CSS на странице при изменении
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({ // Выполняем browserSync
        server: { // Определяем параметры сервера
            baseDir: 'app' // Директория для сервера - app
        },
        notify: false // Отключаем уведомления
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'less'], function() {
    gulp.watch('app/less/**/*.less', ['less']);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь. Пробую,но всеравно не хочет. Выбивает ошибку"Task function should be specified".

Comment: https://github.com/TigranVardanyan/Less вот рабочий проект. Вам только нужно скопировать к себе и сделать npm i

Comment: Спасибо)Я сегодня попробую)Очень вам благодарна!